# Filtering objects with circular reference to itself (ObjectA has property List<ObjectA>)

Tags: java, json, loops, java-stream, circular-reference

I have a large json structure with nested values that I have converted into a list of objects to work with. I'd like to filter out all objects that don't contain a specific property value. Problem is though, that so far all I've come up with is a for loop within a for loop within a for loop (and that's given we know the json structure is only three nested levels). I only want to filter out the objects that do contain an integer (if it's null, it could be a parent containing something valid) or parents that are empty). If I try to stream with flattened - I can filter out all my objects and nested objects but won't I lose my structure?

quick eg.

```
public class ObjectA { 
 Integer id;
 List<ObjectA> sublist;
}


List<ObjectA> fullList;
Set<Integer> keeptheseIntegers;
for (ObjectA obj : fullList) {
  if (obj.getId() != null && !keeptheseIntegers.contains(obj.getId()){
  fullList.remove(obj);
  }  else if (obj.getId() == null && obj.getSubList().size() > 0) {
  for (ObjectA subObj : obj.getSubList()){
   (same thing as above)
  }
}
```

edit - I did realize later that the remove was not working properly and used iterator.remove. still same logical issue though

Comment: Do you mean the ObjectA contains either a valid Integer or a valid subList, but not both?

Comment: I assume the fullList.remove(obj) throws an exception because it is not allowed to change a collection within its own iterator.

Comment: yes will edit that haha I did end up using iterator.remove but same logical problem of needing to loop within the loop etc. Well yes I guess that is correct regarding valid integer/sublist since the end node should be one with the valid integer.

Answer (score 0):

First: instead of manipulating your original structure (remove unwanted) I would collect the wanted items into an own list during the algorithm.

Second: Iterating through nested structures is a good candidate for the recursive pattern.

Third: Using java 8 I would implement it using streams and lambdas.

Something like this:

```
public class ObjectA
{
    Integer id;
    List<ObjectA> sublist;
}

private static final Set<Integer> keeptheseIntegers = new HashSet<>();
static
{
    keeptheseIntegers.add( 1 );
}

private List<ObjectA> filter( List<ObjectA> list)
{
    List<List<ObjectA>> subLists = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ObjectA> result = list.stream()
            // get all objects with sublist and add the sublist to interim subLists:
            .peek( obj -> {
                if ( obj.sublist == null )
                {
                    // assert your assumption that Integer is assigned
                    if ( obj.id == null )
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    subLists.add( obj.sublist );
                }
            } )
            // filter for the objects you want in result:
            .filter( (obj -> obj.id != null && keeptheseIntegers.contains(obj.id)))
            // and convert the resulting stream to a list:
            .collect( Collectors.toList());

    // call this method recusively for all found sublists:
    subLists.forEach( i -> result.addAll(filter( i)) );
    return result;
}
```

and somewher in your main program flow you call it:

```
...
List<ObjectA> fullList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ObjectA> objWithInt = filter( fullList);
// process the received list. Your original fullList is unchanged.
```

Comment: Hey @Heri thanks for the suggestion and apologies for the delay in response- however, it seems that the list created isn't nested at all - so result is just a flattened list vs a list containing the hierachy